# Magento 1 - setTemplate in block class constructor does not work

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, template, overrides

I try to overwrite the template `app\design\frontend\venedor\custom\template\catalog\product\view\options\type\select.phtml` with `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\wr\catalog\product\view\options\type\select.phtml`

So I have rewritten the constructor of the class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select`.

**Hint**: My Extensions Namespace is "WR" and the name of the Extension is "EPO".

```
class WR_EPO_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Options_Type_Select extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        Mage::Log('my constructor was called', 7, "p.log");
        parent::__construct();

        $this->setTemplate('wr/catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml');
    }
```

The rewrite works fine, I get the log entry in *p.log*.

But the old template is still getting loaded. I already cleared the cache.

I successfully replaced another template in **adminhtml** the same way, so why does it not work in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to copy it from `base` to your `current` theme then, you clean a cache :

From :

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml

to :

> app/design/frontend/{current-theme}/{name}/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml

**Note :** with your `wr/` folder it will not work, in this case you should do it via xml. Magento know `catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml`
 and not `wr/catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml`

Update : If you want to change the architecture folders, you can do it via Xml like this :

> app/design/frontend/{current-theme}/{name}/layout/local.xml

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper" >
        <block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
            <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>wr/catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: Is this the only way? Can't I override it?

Comment: Look my update.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the template inside a xml.

Indeed, the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select` class (or parents) does not have a `setTemplate` method in constructor.

The template of this class (`catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml`) is set in `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml:251` (I just looked in the native `rwd` theme but you can find it in base theme too) with

```
<action method="addOptionRenderer">
    <type>select</type>
    <block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block>
    <template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template>    
</action>
```

So you should override it with the xml way.

Comment: I tried to override it via my layout file which is in `app/design/frontend/base/default` but this did not worked too.